# Apache Rewrite condition ignore case

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get the Apache RewriteCond to ignore case when doing a dbm match.

I've tried the following, however, when I do the Apache engine errors out on httpd restart without any meaningful help messages:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lc int:lower
...
RewriteMap ya_item dbm:/etc/httpd/maps/web031034/ItemRedirects.db
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond ${ya_item:$1} ^(?!\s*$).+ [NC]
RewriteCond ${ya_item:$1} ^${lc:(?!\s*$).+} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%0 [NC,L,R=301] 
RewriteCond ${ya_item:$1} ^(?!\s*$).+ [NC]
RewriteCond ${ya_item:$1} ^${lc:(?!\s*$).+} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %0 [NC,L,R=301]
```

The db file is compiled (httxt2dbm) from an all lowercase text file that has a from this to this mapping of urls. If the url is entered in lowercase on the browser or through screaming frog it works just fine. If the case is mixed in any way no match is found.